# The extremum of a closed convex space

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $E$ is a vector space of finite dimension, $K\subset E$ is a compact convex set. Define extrema of $K$ as this set:

Ext($K$)={$c:\forall a,b\in K$,if $c\in[a,b]$, then $c=a$ or $c=b$}

Prove Ext($K$) not empty and$$K=\overline{Conv(Ext(K))}$$, where the overline is closure, conv is the convex envelop.

I've proved the first part(I believe), by arguing the the element with the biggest norm is a extremum. But for the second part, I don't know how to use "finite dimension", by using a basis?

Would someone like to help? Thanks a lot~

Comment: what is Ext ?  Exterior ? Please define it

Comment: How is [a,b] defined?

Comment: @SoumikGhosh ext A = (cl A)^c = int A^c.

Comment: then this is not the extrema of K ?

Comment: Ext is defined in line3, [a,b] = $\{\lambda a + (1-\lambda)b, \lambda\in [0,1]\}$

Comment: please define convex envelope

Comment: @SoumikGhosh the smallest convex set containing the given set

Comment: Cf [Krein-Milman theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krein%E2%80%93Milman_theorem?wprov=sfsi1)